# WhatsApp 'click to chat' with emoticon in the pre-filled text breaks the emoticon on desktop browser

Tags: encoding, whatsapp

I'd like to implement the WhatsApp 'click to chat' with emoticon in the pre-filled message but when I did it and tried it from a desktop browser WhatsApp breaks the emoticon.

I'd like to pre fill the message with the text "Hi from me "

According to documentation [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/) my link behind the 'click to chat' link looks like this:

- https://wa.me/?text=Hi%20from%20me%20%F0%9F%91%8B

where the text (and the emoticon) are url-encoded.

On mobile it works but when trying it from a desktop browser the result is a message like this: "Hi from me �"

Is there a way to pre-fill the WhatsApp message with emoticons and make it work also on desktop browsers?

Many thanks

Comment: It seems that whatsapp redirects to 
https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?text=Hi+from+me+%EF%BF%BD&type=custom_url&app_absent=0 replacing the emoji with the unicode "EF BF BD" REPLACEMENT CHARACTER